# Search and format centered text in Word. - Macro/VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro that searches through my word document to find any text that is centered and apply this formatting to it.

```
With Selection
.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
.Font.Bold = wdToggle
.Font.AllCaps = True
End With
```

I tried

```
Selection.Find.Style = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

But I suppose it's not that easy.

I then gave this a shot,

```
Dim p As Paragraph

For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If p.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter Then
        With Selection
            .Font.Bold = wdToggle
            .Font.AllCaps = True
        End With

    End If
Next p
```

But no luck unfortunately.

Comment: You need to show us your actual code. For example, what is the definition of `Selection`.

Comment: I updated my post hopefully this helps? Let me know if you need more info. Thanks.

Comment: The code worked fine for me. How do you run the code? Function or Sub? Have you tried executing it step-by-step?

Comment: Hi, I'm running it as a Sub. It only seems to work on highlighted text, it will check if any text that is highlighted/selected has any Center alignment and if it does, it will toggle Bold on everything and make everything caps (even if parts of the highlighted/selected text is not center aligned). But I only want it to toggle bold and capitalise only text that is center aligned. - Also without having to highlight everything in the doc. This is what I observed whilst running in debug mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub Bold_All_Caps()
    Dim p As Paragraph

    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If p.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter Then
            With p
                .Range.Font.Bold = True
                .Range.Font.AllCaps = True
            End With

        End If
    Next p
End Sub
```

The Problem was, that you applied the changes (the `With` part) only the selection. If you Change that to the paragraph it works.

Please Change the part `.Range.Font.Bold = True` to `.Range.Font.Bold = wdToggle` if you want to Change the bold typeface instead of applying a bold typeface all the time. The wdToggle will make bold text not bold and vice versa.

Comment: Awesome! That does it. So does p.range select that whole paragraph that it's found to be center aligned?

Comment: The code basically goes through each paragraph (`For Each...`), checks if the paragraph is aligned Center (`If p.Alignment...`) and sets this paragraph Format to bold and allcaps.
However, you should check the functions under the styles tab, there is an Option called "Select all text with similar formatting" which does excatly that.

Comment: That makes sense. I would use that function but I'm trying to create a macro that does multiple different things to the document format/layout. Next on the list, changing any bullet points or lists to a specific list type. - A little off topic but you wouldn't happen to know where I can get the names for these lists, e.g. Bulletpoint is: wdListBullet.

Thank you for all your help :] -- EDIT: Nvm found it here: http://www.thedoctools.com/index.php?show=mt_create_style_name_list :)